# Instruct Dask what records to include in each partition

Tags: python, sql, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I have bank accounts records where each row is the monthly balance of the account:

```
Acct.Number   Date             Balance
1111          2020-03-31        1000
1111          2020-04-30        1300
1111          2020-05-31        1100
1111          2020-06-30        1400
2222          2020-03-31       31000
2222          2020-04-30       32000
2222          2020-05-31       31100
2222          2020-06-30       31300
 .                .               .
 .                .               .
9999          2020-03-31        8000
9999          2020-04-30        8800
9999          2020-05-31        8100
9999          2020-06-30        8500
```

Assume there are 10 million accounts and 10 years of data. What I need to do is to apply a function to each account.

For example, for each account I need to take the mean of the 10 years and calculate the difference between that mean and the balance of that date. For account 1111 it will look like this (the mean is 1200):

```
Acct.Number   Date             Balance     Difference
1111          2020-03-31        1000       -200
1111          2020-04-30        1300        100
1111          2020-05-31        1100       -100
1111          2020-06-30        1400        200
```

This is my thinking: once I have the data in multiple Dask partitions where each partition contains N accounts, with `map_partitions` I can process in parallel the accounts in each partition.

This works if an account with all its dates is in a single partition. If I let Dask arbitrarily separate the data into partitions, this will not happen. Is there a way to instruct Dask what data should be included in each partition?

As a side note, I create the Dask dataframe and partitions with Dask [read_sql_query](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_sql_query.html). The data is ordered by account/date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is sorted by account, when loading the dataframe using `read_sql_query` function, specifying `index_col="Acct.Number"` will make sure that each partition contains information on a specific account number. It's also possible for multiple partitions to contain a specific account details, but the operations on these partitions will be faster, because dask will be aware of their contents.

Comment: Sultan, the data is ordered by Account Number + Date. Can I set the index to multiple fields, something like `index_col="Acct.Number,Date"` ? I need the data also ordered by date inside the `map_partitions` function.

Comment: Also. what if I create the dataframe with `dd.from_pandas` ? I don't see in that function the `index_col` parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, `index_col` accepts only a single column right now. `dd.from_pandas`will use the index information of the pandas dataframe, so if your pandas dataframe is indexed by `acct.number`, then the dask dataframe should also be (but it won't work for multi-indexed dataframes I think)...

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Provided index column is of type "object".  If divisions is not provided the index column type must be numeric or datetime.` I don't want to provide the divisions, I want Dask to calculate the divisions for me. I guess that I will have to make the divisions manually because the account number is a string, not a number.

Comment: Hmmm, it should be possible to convert string to numbers within sql (I'm not familiar with the syntax).

Comment: The account can contain characters. This is how I solved this: I hash the account number from string into a number, and use that number as the index

Comment: Hashing can lead to collisions, it's a rare event, but still... what I had in mind is literally a separate table that lists unique strings and then attaches a sequential number to each string. e.g. 'aaa' is 1, 'aab' is 2, etc. I've done this in the past, just forgot the commands I used.

Comment: yes, that's also a good idea

Comment: Sultan, if I create the dataframe with `from_pandas` there's a sort attribute that defaults to yes. If the Pandas dataframe is already sorted by account number/balance date, do I need to set to False this attribute? `Sort the input by index first to obtain cleanly divided partitions (with known divisions). If False, the input will not be sorted, and all divisions will be set to None. Default is True.`

Comment: Hmm, if you set it to False, then there is no guarantee that partitions will be cleanly separated based on the account (so it's possible that some of the account info is in partition 3 and some of it in partition 4). The order is going to be preserved (dask will not sort by itself, but I might be wrong on this), but you would need to do additional work to ensure your groupby's use the relevant partitions.